# Dagger 2 + Event bus

Tags: android, dagger-2, otto

I want to send data from the activity to my fragment using otto event bus

From my activity:

```
@Produce
public EventAvailableEvent produceEvent() {
    return new EventAvailableEvent(mEvent);
}
```

To fragment:

```
@Subscribe
public void onProvideEvent(EventAvailableEvent event) {
    mEvent = event.getEvent();
}
```

I'm using dagger 2 to inject bus

```
@Inject Bus mBus;

private void injectDepedencies() {
    App.from(getActivity()).getComponent().plus(new MyModule(mEvent));
}
```

My module is dependant to the event returned by event bus.

Right now, what I do is inject first the main component, register bus, then inject subcomponent

```
AppComponent appComponent = App.from(getActivity()).getComponent();
appComponent.inject(this)
mBus.register(this)
SubComponent subComponent = appComponent.plus(new MyModule(mEvent));
subComponent.inject(this)
```

I'm looking for a better way to this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I guess your SubComponent is a subcomponent of AppComponent it inherits all of it's provided items. [Described here](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Component.html#component-relationships)

> That relationship allows the subcomponent implementation to inherit the entire binding graph from its parent when it is declared.

This means, you can just kick out the first 2 lines and that you just have to create your SubComponent.

```
App.from(getActivity()).getComponent().plus(new MyModule(mEvent)).inject(this);
mBus.register(this);
```

Would actually be enough.